# Not able to download json file through url (Flutter/dart)

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart, http

I'd like to download the JSON file which can be accessed by this url https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/prufungssimulation-caff9.appspot.com/o/5qPfjoZjdNXyN5Ob2q3pFbj5MKy1.json?alt=media. Unfortunately I was not able to download this file with the http get-function. I assume that I have some problem with the parsing since if I remove "?alt=media" it works perfectly, but unfortunately I only get the meta-json file. This is the code which I use:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

[...]
[...]


void testFunction(){

    var url_string = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/prufungssimulation-caff9.appspot.com/o/5qPfjoZjdNXyN5Ob2q3pFbj5MKy1.json?alt=media";

    var result = await getJsonFromFirebaseRestAPI(url_string);

    print(result);
}

Future<String> getJsonFromFirebaseRestAPI(String url) async {

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    return response.body;
  }
```

The JSON file result should look like this:
`routes: []`
It's basically empty I'm just trying to implement the function.

I use `http: ^0.13.5`

I get the following error:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 299:10
createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 341:28
_throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 116:5
throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1378:11
callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11
_microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5
_startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15
<fn>
```

Can anybody solve my issue?

Appreciate your time :)

Comment: What's the error log? Can you post it?

Comment: thank you I've just edited my question. Do you have any idea?

Comment: That's CORS, the API or URL is being blocked over Flutter Web. You'll not be able to use it unless that domain allows you to. In case of Firebase Storage, you need to whitelist domains or any domain over the Google Console.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla thank you very much for this input!! This make sense :) but sadly I don't know how to whitelist my local host do you have any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I did few changes on your code and it is working. There was no issue with the get function. here is the updated piece

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// just a normal main to test the function in terminal
void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  await testFunction();
}

// changed this to future and made it async
Future<void> testFunction() async {
  var url_string = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/prufungssimulation-caff9.appspot.com/o/5qPfjoZjdNXyN5Ob2q3pFbj5MKy1.json?alt=media";
  var result = await getJsonFromFirebaseRestAPI(url_string);
  print(result);
}

// no changes applied here.
Future<String> getJsonFromFirebaseRestAPI(String url) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  return response.body;
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much but somhow it didn't work on flutter chrom (web). Where did you try it?

Comment: I tried it with a console project. it worked like a charm.